# foreach inside function returning blank items after first run

Tags: php

So I created a function with a foreach to process arrays:

```
<?php
function listFeat($feature) {
echo '<ul class="highlight-ul">';
    foreach ($feature as $key => $value){
        echo '<li class="highlight-ul">';
        echo $value['highlight'];
        echo '</li>';
    }
    unset($value);
echo '</ul>';

}
?>
```

But when I call it twice:

```
<h2>prod</h2>
<?php listFeat($p_feat); ?>

<h2>mom</h2>
<?php listFeat($m_feat); ?>
```

I get this result:

PROD

- array item
- array item

MOM

- shows empty li
- shows empty li

I cant figure out why?

Comment: It obviously depends on what you pass it. So what does `$m_feat` look like?

Comment: Hey. What's going on here? Another @Don'tPanic?

Comment: Hey! Another @Don'tPanic! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in function `listFeat` is okay. More, you don't need to do `unset($value);` as it is a local variable and it is never used further.

Most probably, the `m_feat` is not initialized properly or it has a wrong reference, if you use them.

Comment: I went back and tripple checked this. I say with flushed cheeks... you were right. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're calling `unset($value);` during the loop. It essentially clears the variable. Remove the `unset()` call and it should work as expected.

Judging by your example though, `$p_feat` and `$m_feat` seem to refer to the same array object. That's why the first call also clears the second call.

Comment: Removed unset and still the same issue :(

Comment: Are you sure `$m_feat` is an array and has values then? Especially under the 'highlight' key.

Comment: @SonyThePony then your variable probably does not contain what you thing it contains. Try a `var_dump($m_feat)` to debug and check if it really has what you expect.

Comment: yeah, if i run a foreach for each array variable ($p_feat and $m_feat) and change the name of the $value to a unique one for each it works.

Comment: @SonyThePony that's not possible, it's not how it works. Please edit the question and post the `var_dump`  of both `$p_feat` and `$m_feat`

Comment: This answer makes no sense.  1. `$value` is local, inside the function.  You can do what you want to it and it won't affect any `$value` outside the function.  2. Even if there was a `$value` outside, how would unsetting that affect `$m_feat`?

Comment: If they keep a reference to the same array, it would affect them both.